# sync Azure AD with another idedity provider

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We have a delay issue with users from China signing to our Azure AD.
We were thinking how to find a solution that will resolve the issue.
One solution is to use an identity provider hosted in China and sync users from Azure AD.
I'm not sure if it's possible to sync identities from AzureAD back to another provider?
Or is there any better way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD is region Agnostic, however due to intermediary cross-order regulatory technologies for traffic coming in and out of china a certain degree of latency gets added. It may be possible that the users are getting auth tokens from azure AD a little later in china region that normally they get in other regions. You should check as to what is the baseline for your environment in terms of latency. You mention that the issue is specific to china region. So I assume you have some web asset (like web app hosted on azure or any other cloud) , and while accessing the same , the users in china region face latency issues. [Azure Documentation have a section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/china/concepts-performance-and-connectivity#network-latency-in-china) describing the same.

For better experience of your users in China , you can host an instance of the application in China region and deploy CDN solutions which would provide faster access to the user after Azure AD authentication. As per the [article shared from the azure china playbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/china/concepts-performance-and-connectivity#global-connectivity-and-interoperability) , you can find the following information useful.

A hybrid cloud can extend your applications or workloads in Azure China, and provide global connectivity and interoperability. The following connections are supported:

- Use a virtual private network (VPN) or Azure ExpressRoute to create a
  direct network connection between Azure and your on-premises private
  cloud or back-end systems within China.
- Set up a site-to-site VPN to connect an Azure site in China to your on-premises location outside of China. ExpressRoute is not supported for direct network connectivity to an external (outside of China) site. Even Azure
  global is considered external.

Now coming to your original question about using another identity provider. I doubt using that will help in this case unless you are using an Identity provider within China region . There are other many identity providers which which the azure AD identities can be synced but every provider have different capabilities and may or may not be at parity with Azure AD completely in terms of attributes' synced and features/capabilities available. I do not have experience with setting up cross-country tech infrastructure involving china but I think some latency is expected as far as what i have read due to internet design between china and rest of the world.

If you have On-premise active directory as well which is synced to Azure AD , you can setup a site to site VPN and add a few domain controller in china for your users. This only applies if you have on-premise active directory environment . If not this may not be a solution for you .